# Root of real and complex polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ be a root of real polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k$ ,$a_k\in \mathbb{R} \forall k$.

How to proove, that $\overline{z}$ is also a root of given polynomial? Is that true for complex polynomials, too?

Comment: Did you try to take the complex conjugate of the whole equation $\sum a_kx^k=0$?

Comment: If $p(z)=0$, then $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k z^k=0$. Hence $0=\overline{\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k z^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k \overline{z}^k$ since the coefficients are real. For complex polynomials this do not hold - consider the linear case, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that complex conjugation can be interchanged with products and sums. Plug in $\overline{z}$ an use this repeatedly.

Note that $a \overline{z}= \overline{az}$ when $a$ is real yet not in general.

Answer (score 1):

May be $z_0=x+iy$ a root of the polynomial $p$. Then, if $\bar{z_0} = x-iy$ is also a root then the polynomial can be divided by $(z-z_0)(z-\bar{z_0}) = (z-x)^2+y^2 \in R$ because the numbers $x,y$ are real numbers.

For complex polynomials, this relation does not hold.

Comment: I think you have it exactly backward.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $z=re^{i\theta}.$

> **If you set $b_k=ra_k$ then the polynomial
>   $$q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} b_k x^k$$ has the zero $e^{i\theta}$ if and only if $$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k$$ has the zero $z=re^{i\theta}.$**

If $b_k\in\mathbb{R},$ then all $a_k\in\mathbb{R},$ and by [D'Moivers theorem](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDe_Moivre%2527s_formula&ei=yC_rVNrbBcTZ8gXKzID4Ag&usg=AFQjCNG4RQ4D8o0S1x_I4fLQQb2zCGol1g&bvm=bv.86475890,d.dGY)
$$q(e^{i\theta})=0\iff\sum^n_{k=0}b_k\left(\cos k\theta+i\sin k\theta\right)=0$$
$$q(e^{i\theta})=0\iff\sum^n_{k=0}b_k\cos k\theta+i\sum^n_{k=0}b_k\sin k\theta=0$$
$$q(e^{i\theta})=0\iff\sum^n_{k=0}b_k\cos k\theta=0 ,\,\,\text{and} \sum^n_{k=0}b_k\sin k\theta=0$$
$$q(e^{i\theta})=0\iff\sum^n_{k=0}b_k\cos k\theta-i\sum^n_{k=0}b_k\sin k\theta=0$$
$$q(e^{i\theta})=0\iff q(e^{-i\theta})=0.$$
Hence $$p(re^{i\theta})=0\iff p(re^{-i\theta})=0.$$